# How can I make a directive call a function each time an input attribute changes?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following in my HTML:

```
<markdown abc="{{ q.qv.text }}"></markdown>
```

and this directive:

```
app.directive('markdown', function () {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(attrs.abc);
            element.html(htmlText);
        }
    }
});
```

When the page appears I make an HTTP call to get data, the directive works, get the **last** value of the q.qv.text and displays it. After this the HTTP call returns and populates q.qv.text.

But by that time the **old** value of q.qv.text is already displayed.

How can I make it so that this directive reacts to changes in q.qv.text and calls the converter.makeHTML to process the new value?

Comment: It's sad that SO has posters who mark down this question without explanation. Hopefully next time that person asks a question then someone will give them the answer they deserve :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you put a watch on the variable  : 
[AngularJS Watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch)

```
    app.directive('markdown', function () {
        var converter = new Showdown.converter();
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
                    abc: '=abc'
                }
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
               scope.$watch('abc',function(newvalue){
                 element.html(newvalue);
               });

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your answer has some syntax errors and it misses out var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(attrs.abc);

Comment: It was just to point the difference between accessing the abc variable via scope and attrs.abc, attrs.abc will read whatever is in the attribute as a text, but when accessed via scope you can benefit from the two way databinding. i hope that it was a useful answer anyway. ( sorry for my bad english )